# Are salesforce id predictables?

Tags: salesforce, document, brute-force

I'm wondering if it's possible to predict a salesforce document id. They all start with prefix `069` and there are additional 12 [a-Z] + [0-9] chars. My questions are:

Is it possible that 2 document ids are the same on two different salesforce instances?

Are these ids easy to brute force from a security perspective?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that 2 document ids are the same on two different
> salesforce instances?

Yes. Create a document in production, then refresh a full copy sandbox. Or create document in a sandbox and then clone it. User ids, documents, record type ids will stay same. There's some fascinating reading on ids in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of

> Are these ids easy to bruteforce

Yes. What's your concern. You can limit access to document folders by group/role/single named user. If you use Files (ContentDocument, ContentVersion) you can have some more sharing options like being linked to a record or not. If you're concerned a guest user (unauthenticated) can patiently try to guess documents exposed in community - don't expose them that way.

Sounds like you have a sharing rules problem, not Id generation problem?